# State observer for speed estimation from encoder

Tags: control-engineering

I try to implement a state observer (Luenberg Observer) to estimate the speed of my motor. Only the absolute position of the motor can be measured and I want to take into account also the target velocity as the input.

So my derived state space model looks like this:

The states are position, velocity and acceleration
$$
x = \begin{pmatrix}
p \\
v  \\
a
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The Input is the velocity target vi minus the estimated velocity state:

$$
u=(v_i-v)
$$

The system matrices looks like this (T is the sampling time):
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & T & \frac{T^2}{2} \\
0 & 1 & T  \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
B = \begin{pmatrix}
T \\
1  \\
\frac{1}{T} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
C = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
D=0
$$

When I move the input -v into the A matrix, it looks like this:

$$
x_{k+1} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \frac{T^2}{2} \\
0 & 0 & T  \\
0 & -\frac{1}{T} & 0 
\end{pmatrix} x_k + \begin{pmatrix}
T \\
1  \\
\frac{1}{T} 
\end{pmatrix} v_i
$$

$$
y_k= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} x_k
$$

So I tried to place the poles of the error dynamics with a Luenberg observer by choosen L for:

$$
A-LC = \begin{pmatrix}
1-L_1 & 0 & \frac{T^2}{2} \\
-L2 & 0 & T  \\
-L3 & -\frac{1}{T} & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I placed the poles in matlab as follows:
$$ |\lambda_i|<1$$
 at [-0.5,-0.55,-0.6]

Which gave me for L:

$$
L = \begin{pmatrix}
2.65 \\
2.92 \times 10^3  \\
-1.9 \times 10^5
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So I embedded this observer in the real system, but the results are actually very bad. So I think I did something wrong with the state space model, especially the input u seems not to be a good idea. Has anyone an idea how else I can model this system, especially about the input u I'm very unsure. Should I use the actual current as input for u, since this is proportional to the torque and so the acceleration?

**Edit:** What i further see is, that state a is not observable (Observability matrix has determinante different from zero), but since I don't want to observe the acceleration (I give this directly as an input), I think this should not be a problem, right?

**Edit 2** Well, my Luenberger gains are pretty high, so I think that might be a problem. I update the state as follows:

$$
x_{k+1}=(A-LC)x_k + B v_i + Ly_k
$$

y is my measured position at instance k, so let's say this is 4000 (12 bit encode resolution). Initially my states are zero. Then the acceleration will be directly 4000*(-1.9 * 10^5), huge! So  I think I really messed up something here.

Comment: Is the observer fast enough? Rule of thumb for a Luenberg observer is, to place its poles about 10 times as fast as the system poles

Comment: Good question, I'm not sure about this. I need a bandwidth of 2kHz, how can I calculate the bandwidth of poles for a discrete transfer function?

Comment: Careful, at low speeds encoder based speed estimators can break down. If you are using a counter to measure time between encoder line, the counter size will limit your low end speed estimate. And the counter rate your upper end.

Answer (score 1):

Acceleration shouldn't be part of the state unless you jerk would be your input. And tracking a target velocity seems more of a job for the controller using feedback. So your system input is more likely a force, which induces an acceleration, and the states position and velocity.

Inorder for an observer to work well you need to provide it with a good model of your system. Namely the motor will likely have some friction and maybe even some delay. For obtaining a model you could for example try to fit a [ARIMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average) model onto measured data or use [ERA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigensystem_realization_algorithm). The state space representation of a (minimal) LTI system is not unique, namely they are equivalent under a [similarity transformation](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Representations/SysRepTransformations/SS2SS.html). So if it is desired to have a state vector with position and velocity, you could obtain this by using a similarity transformation.